# Are there limitations converting a WCF OData Service to a Web API OData Service?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

We have some legacy OData service code in our application which is written using a WCF Data Service.

Everything else in our system now uses Web API as the data interface so I am wanting to port our WCF OData Service to a Web API service with the OData annotations.

My question is, we currently use the OData service for standard CRUD statements and also a lot of Service Operations. Are there any limitations with Web API OData that would limit it compared to WCF Data Services (i.e relationship chains, service operation calls, etc.)? I'm wanting to get away with updating the service so the client side of things doesn't have to change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started working on a similar port from WCF to WebAPI for OData with the recent release of Web API 2 and its support for $select and $expand - until then I could not really replace the data service. Service operations can be added as [actions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions)

Comment: Hi eoghank, thanks for your response. Can I ask, have you found any performance improvements converting to WebAPI? What made your decision to do the convert?

Comment: We were already using Web API for standard ApiControllers so it suited us to have everything Web API based, I also prefer overriding actions for POST, PATCH etc than using the WCF interceptors. We haven't done sufficient performance testing yet to notice any difference.